# Sync iPhone contacts with MacBook

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, contacts

I am not seeing how to sync my iPhone contacts with my computer contacts.  It's an iPhone 5s and a 2008 MacBook. How can I move my phone contacts to my computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using iCloud to manage your contacts you can sync the contacts manually with your computer.

1. Connect the device to iTunes over USB.
2. In iTunes, choose your phone from the toolbar and select the Info tab.

   > [image]

   [iTunes for Mac: Sync contacts, calendars, and other info with iPod, iPhone, or iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19462)
3. Check the box beside Sync Contacts and press Apply.